# Testcafe: hide part of DOM elements during screenshots

Tags: typescript, testcafe, visual-testing

I am doing some visual testings using Testcafe (Typescript)
I would like to hide some DOM elements during the screenshots creation

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`Getting Started`
    .page`https://mypage.com`;

test('My first test', async t => {
    // select certains elements before
    await t.takeScreenshot()
});
```

A visual exemple would be
To go from this image
[image]

to this image
[image]

Any suggestion on how to do this apart from "reinventing the wheel" hard coding some pixel selection code ?
Thanks

Comment: If you are willing to consider percy, this link has some details around the ask: https://docs.percy.io/docs/percy-specific-css.  percy has testcafe integration too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ClientFunction`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402671/reference/test-api/clientfunction) and hide the element manually with JS.

```js
test('Hide element', async t => {
    const hideElement = ClientFunction(() => {
        document.querySelector('#id').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
  
    await hideElement();
  
    await t.expect(Selector('#id').visible).notOk();
});
```

Also, you can use [`clientScripts` hook for `fixture`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402783/reference/test-api/fixture/clientscripts) or [`clientScripts` hook for `test`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402737/reference/test-api/test/clientscripts) in the same way.